# Pythonic Improvement Of Function In List Comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is there a more pythonic way to do the following code?  I would like to do it in one line

parsed_rows is a function that can return a tuple of size 3, or None.

```
parsed_rows = [ parse_row(tr) for tr in tr_els ]        
data        = [ x for x in parsed_rows if x is not None ]
```

Comment: You can make `parsed_rows` a generator so you don't have to materialize an intermediate list.

Answer (score 8):

Doing this in one line won't make it more Pythonic; it will make it less readable. If you really want to, you can always translate it directly by substitution like this:

```
data = [x for x in [parse_row(tr) for tr in tr_els] if x is not None]
```

… which can obviously be flattened as Doorknob of Snow shows, but it's still hard to understand. However, he didn't get it quite right: clauses nest from left to right, and you want `x` to be each `parse_row` result, not each element of each `parse_row` result (as Volatility points out), so the flattened version would be:

```
data = [x for tr in tr_els for x in (parse_row(tr),) if x is not None]
```

I think the fact that a good developer got it backward and 6 people upvoted it before anyone realized the problem, and then I missed a second problem and 7 more people upvoted that before anyone caught it, is pretty solid proof that this is not more pythonic or more readable, just as Doorknob said. :)

In general, when faced with either a nested comp or a comp with multiple `for` clauses, if it's not immediately obvious what it does, you should translate it into nested `for` and `if` statements with an innermost `append` expression statement, as shown in [the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). But if you need to do that with a comprehension you're trying to write, it's a pretty good sign you shouldn't be trying to write it…

---

However, there *is* a way to make this more Pythonic, and also more efficient: change the first list comprehension to a generator expression, like this:

```
parsed_rows = (parse_row(tr) for tr in tr_els)
data = [x for x in parsed_rows if x is not None]
```

All I did is change the square brackets to parentheses, and that's enough to compute the first one *lazily*, calling `parse_row` on each `tr` as needed, instead of calling it on all of the rows, and building up a list in memory that you don't actually need, before you even get started on the real work.

In fact, if the only reason you need `data` is to iterate over it once (or to convert it into some other form, like a CSV file or a NumPy array), you can make that a generator expression as well.

---

Or, even better, replace the list comprehension with a [`map`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#map) call. When your expression is just "call this function on each element", `map` is generally more readable (whereas when you have to write a new function, especially with `lambda`, just to wrap up some more complex expression, it's usually not). So:

```
parsed_rows = map(parse_row, tr_els)
data = [x for x in parsed_rows if x is not None]
```

And now it actually *is* readable to sub in:

```
data = [x for x in map(parse_row, tr_els) if x is not None]
```

---

You could similarly turn the second comprehension into a [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) call. However, just as with `map`, if the predicate isn't just "call this function and see if it returns something truthy", it usually ends up being less readable. In this case:

```
data = filter(lambda x: x is not None, map(parse_row, tr_els))
```

But notice that you really don't need to check `is not None` in the first place. The only non-`None` values you have are 3-tuples, which are always truthy. So, you can replace the `if x is not None` with `if x`, which can simplifies your comprehension:

```
data = [x for x in map(parse_row, tr_else) if x]
```

… and which can be written in two different ways with `filter`:

```
data = filter(bool, map(parse_row, tr_els))
data = filter(None, map(parse_row, tr_els))
```

Asking which of those two is better will start a religious war on any of the Python lists, so I'll just present them both and let you decide.

---

Note that if you're using Python 2.x, `map` is not lazy; it will generate the whole intermediate list. So, if you want to get the best of both worlds, and can't use Python 3, use `itertools.imap` instead of `map`. An in the same way, in 3.x, `filter` *is* lazy, so if you want a list, use `list(filter(…))`.

Comment: +1, but I think the second code should be `data = [x for tr in tr_els for x in (parse_row(tr),) if x is not None]` (I'm nitpicking though)

Comment: @Volatility: Oh, right; `parsed_row` returns a single row, not a sequence.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: But that's the same as `if x`, not `if x is not None`, which will filter out zeros, empty strings, etc.

Comment: @abarnert: to be fair, the OP said the only two options were tuple-of-three and None.

Comment: @DSM: In that case, he shouldn't have been using `is not None` in the first place… so I'll edit the answer.

Comment: [Non-warlike thought: I think `None` would have been a great shortcut for `is not None`.. oh, well.]

Comment: @DSM: I think not allowing `None` at all would have been best… But the current behavior makes sense for historical reasons (which Guido hasn't written up on python-history, but you can mostly infer it from `filter` being one of the first non-Guido-driven language changes back in the 1.x days, when `bool` and even `lambda` didn't exist).

Answer (score 5):

You can nest one in the other:

```
data = [x for tr in tr_els for x in parse_row(tr) if x is not None]
```

(Also, @Volatility points out that this will give an error if `parse_row(tr)` is `None`, which can be solved like this:

```
data = [x for tr in tr_els for x in (parse_row(tr),) if x is not None]
```

)

However, in my opinion this is much less readable. Shorter is not always better.

Comment: +1, shorter is not always better. Giving a name to the intermediate data puts explicit intent in the code

Comment: With nested comprehensions I usually format it so that each `for` is on a different line, but I guess that defeats the purpose of the question!

Comment: Isn't this an array comprehension with a generator expression though (rather than nested array comprehensions), just to nit-pick? Not sure about it myself, so this is a serious question :)

Comment: @roe Heh, I'm actually not sure about that myself, since I don't usually use Python. I'll just edit it out

Comment: Shouldn't there be square brackets around the `parsed(tr) for tr in tr_els`? Because otherwise it would give a `NameError`

Comment: @roe: No, it's not a listcomp with a genexpr in it, _or_ a listcomp with another listcomp nested in it; it's a single listcomp with nested `for` clauses. But it's backward, so it won't work.

Comment: This has six upvotes, but I don't think it actually works.  It's `for x in parse_row(tr): for tr in tr_els: if x is not None: data.append(x)`, and that's misordered.

Comment: @abarnert; cool, thanks for clearing it up. Yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow: No, as I said, `for` clauses nest left to right. So this first does `for x in parse_row(tr)`, which raises a `NameError`, and then it would later do `for tr in tr_else`, which would have worked but it never gets that far.

Comment: @abarnert Ah, okay. Corrected. (I really don't use Python that much)

Comment: In general, when you're trying to work out a complicated listcomp, translate it to explicit `for` statements, `if` statements, and an `append` and it will make sense. [The tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) shows how to translate it.

Comment: This will give an error (can't remember which) when `parse_row(tr) is None`, and you try to loop through it. See my comment to @abarnert's answer.